# Mosaic Raster Function Error ArcGIS Pro 2

Tags: arcgis-pro, mosaic, raster-functions

I have a class of GIS students who are attempting to use the Mosaic Raster Function in ArcGIS Pro to stitch together three small raster clips.  For most, the function is working fine but some are experiencing a general error where the function just does not work.  The error just states that it could not be completed.  They all seem to be using the same imagery as raster inputs.  They are all selecting the same operation and they are working on the same type of computer with the same version of ArcGIS Pro.

Is there some other variable that we should be considering which could be causing this very general error?

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say this is caused by either input/output file locations or naming conventions. Other than that, are you mosaicing to an existing raster or mosaicing the inputs to a new raster? they are 2 different functions.

Comment: What is the error?  Any other details than "it could not be completed"?  Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: I did not get a screenshot before class ended Thursday.  I will have a student replicate tomorrow and submit since I cannot create the error myself.